# How to check TLS1.2 is supported in .NET

Tags: .net, tls1.2

My application requires TLS1.2, is it possible to check if the environment **supports** TLS1.2?
I thought about having this on installation phase or in a small .NET app to test it before getting to the HTTP call

Comment: you can force certain TLS flag and check if the request is passing.

Comment: ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

Comment: you can set the same for individual service point.

Comment: Thank you @ParimalRaj, I'm currently setting `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` on my app. I want a more explicit check than trying to pass an HTTP call and parse its failure

Comment: check the application nmap, it can do assessment for SSL protocols.